# FileSystem API - Recursively listing files from directory drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

I have a loop that lists files in a directory. It's working fine going down the first level.

```
Folder/1.jpg
Folder/2.jpg
```

etc.

But if I have a folder inside the main folder...

```
Folder/nestedFolder/
```

The console.log spits out

```
nestedFolder/1.jpg
```

but I want it to log

```
Folder/nestedFolder/1.jpg
```

Here's my method

```
function traverseFileTree(item,path){
  path = path || "";
  if (item.isFile){
    console.log(path + item.name);
  } else if (item.isDirectory){
    var directoryPath = item.name
    var dirReader = item.createReader();
    dirReader.readEntries(function(entries){
      for (var i=0; i < entries.length; i++){
        traverseFileTree(entries[i], directoryPath + "/")
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and this is where directories are being passed in

```
function handleDrop(e) {
  var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
  var length = items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if(item){
      traverseFileTree(item);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: How do you pass in the arguments?

Comment: Can't you just append `item.name` to existing `directoryPath` instead of replacing the value?  Then you'll preserve the entire path rather than just the current directory. i.e. `var directoryPath += item.name`

Comment: @aarosil `var directoryPath += item.name` is invalid syntax and directoryPath is not saved from one step of the loop to the next... but your idea gave me the answer! `var directoryPath = path + item.name
`

Answer (score -1):

Just had to change

```
var directoryPath = item.name
```

to

```
var directoryPath = path + item.name
```